# Works with one compiler, but not with other

Tags: c

I'm trying to code a very simple program using C language.
I'm using Visual Studio and CodeBlocks to make it compiled.

But this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float a;

    printf("Give a number: \n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    float b = a * 2;
    printf("The result is: %f", b);

}
```

It works using CodeBlocks, but not with Visual Studio.
Could you please give me a hint?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4996   'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. Variables   c:\users\PinkP\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\variables\variables.c  32
```

Comment: VS gives you a warning, not an error. The code should still work.

Comment: It doesn't run, it gives me a random number only.

Comment: It is recommending that you use [`scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) instead of `scanf`

Comment: It works finally!

Comment: Codeblocks and Visual Studio are IDE's not compilers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%f", &a);` is considered unsafe by the Visual Studio compiler and they rather cheekily schedule the function for deprecation. (Although ISO have no such plans.) Really they want you to use `scanf_s` instead, as that's less likely to mess up your memory.

You can disable this warning by following the compiler message: i.e. `#define` `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.

The irony here is the compiler permits your non-standard `main()` function without a twitch! Do consider using the more portable

`int main()`

which has been required since and including C99.

Comment: What is the difference for the compiler using 
      main() and int main()?

Comment: @pinkP On any compiler that accepts both almost certainly no difference. However the C standard doesn't permit `main()` so you're quite unnecessarily writing non-standard C. As you get along with C you'll discover that if at all possible conforming to the standard will be easier. You at least won't get perpetually admonished on Stack Overflow for you deviancy.

Comment: @PinkP: Prior to the C99 standard, nothing - C used to allow implicit `int` typing on function definitions.  That changed in the C99 standard, and now all functions *must* be explicitly typed.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 is stricter about deprecated functions than 2010 was.

Rather than just advising you that you need to do something about your use of `scanf`, as Visual Studio 2010 did, it now FORCES you to do something about it.

You need to switch to `scanf_s` or use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.